# Is there analogue for dictionary in J? Or how to implement it

Tags: j

I mean datatype "dictionary". Like in python language. 'key':'value' storage.
I've implemented it using complex numbers. Real part stands for 'key', imaginary - for 'value'.

```
storage =: 10j7 5j6 16j5 8j4 4j3 2j2 1j1
get =: (1&{@+.)@(]#~(=0&{@+.))
   16 get storage
5
```

But I very doubt that it's a good solution.
Also it would be useful to have analogue for set datatype.

Comment: There is no build in dictionary data type. A starting point on how to make one can be found in [DataStructures Essay](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Essays/DataStructures#Associative_Array)

Answer (score 1):

You can see examples of dictionaries and hashes, written in J, at Rosettacode.org:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Associative_array/Creation#J

and

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Associative_array/Iteration#J

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at symbols implemented using the s: primitive and see if that suffices.

http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dsco.htm

Comment: Can you provide an example of the way in which symbols can be used like a dictionary?

Comment: If the goal is to have the keys lead to values that can be changed, I don't think symbols help. If the values are not mutable, then the symbols themselves are the values and they are stored in the order that they are saved. You can use _6 s: index to return a value and 6 s: value to find an index.